# Turbolinks causes JavaScript file to run several times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 5.1.4, I'm new on the platform and I have problems with turboblinks, I have a file containing jquery code that has to run once the page loads, but Whenever the page loads the file runs several times but when I disable the turboblinks there it works as I want it. So I would like to know if there is one less to fix it without turning off the turboblinks. Thank you in advance..

So there is my layout file.// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Rails web app</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-
   track' => true %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>
 <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

  <div class="container">
   <%= yield %>
  </div>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true 
  %>
 </body>
</html>
```

About my js file as you will see i try to load automatically a bootstrap modal with an animation when the page loaded, actually the problem happens when i clik to any link on this page which takes me to another page and i try to come back to the initial page where the js file is loaded, then the problem happens. i see the page refresh many times and the js file as well.

So there is my js file with jquery code. //app/assets/javascripts/file.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('.modal .modal-dialog').attr('class', 'modal-dialog animated rollOut');
  });
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('.modal .modal-dialog').attr('class', 'modal-dialog  fadeIn  
    animated');
  });

  $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Comment: There are indeed ways to fix this problem.  Please post your layout file where you are loading turbolinks and the rest of your javascript.  Also, please post the code you want to run when the page loads.  I also need to know how that code is being included.  i.e. is it part of your JS assets or is it part of a view.

Comment: Hi! @TomAranda, thanks for answering me, so i updated my question with the code, hope you will understand me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turbolinks replaces the body so put this line in your head tag :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Like this :

```
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Rails web app</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 </head>
 <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

  <div class="container">
   <%= yield %>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

or add `data-turbolinks-eval=false` to the script tag that includes turbolinks.

Also you need use the turbolinks:load event :

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('.modal .modal-dialog').attr('class', 'modal-dialog animated rollOut');
  });
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('.modal .modal-dialog').attr('class', 'modal-dialog  fadeIn  
    animated');
  });

  $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Hi! @serpent , I tried your purpose but it doesn't work for me,  always the same problem when I come back to the page  wich containing the modal after living in it. The turboblinks refreshs my page many times on one action and I think that's why my jquery function is called again and again. hope you see what I mean,  thank for your answer,  and thank in advance for anything.

Comment: You mean move it to the header of page,  because I already have it before the end of my body tag.

Comment: if you want to keep it before the end of your body tag add data-turbolinks-eval=false

Comment: @serpent thank very much it fixed my problem, thank I wish you the best,  have a nice day.